# For em um array AJAX

Tags: javascript

Recebo os dados de uma API com um array que e faço o parse dele com js puro.

Esse array me retorna mais de um objeto que atualmente estou exibindo somente no console.log do browser. Eu não sei fazer um for em js puro. Como faço para fazer um for e depois exibir os dados deste array na página com os objetos separados. Quando recebo um só eu faço o seguinte:

```
    if(xhr.status == 200){


      let curso = xhr.responseText;
      curso = JSON.parse(curso);

      let video = '';
      video += curso.video;
      document.querySelector('#video').innerHTML = video;

      let descricao ='';
      descricao += curso.descricao;
      document.querySelector('#curso-descricao').innerHTML = descricao;

    }
```

Desta forma ele exibe os dados de video e descrição, mas é somente com um objeto. Como faço para fazer essa mesma ação para listar os objetos no meu frontend usando js puro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz desta forma e deu certo:

```
if(xhr.status == 200) {
  let aulas = xhr.responseText;
  aulas = JSON.parse(aulas);

  let x = document.querySelector('#videos');
  aulas.map(item => {
    x.innerHTML += '<a href="responde-exercicio.php?id=' + item.id + '"><span>' + item.video + '</span></a>';
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser feito da seguinte maneira:

```
for(var i=0; i <= curso.length; i++){
  //Faça o que quiser acessando os objetos do array pelo indice
  //utilizando o i como exemplo abaixo.

  console.log("video: " + curso[i].video);
  console.log("descricao : " + curso[i].descricao);
}
```

Uma dica é sempre verificar se há alguma coisa no array:

```
if(curso !== null && curso !== undefined && curso.length > 0 ){
//o for vai aqui
}
```

Comment: Fiz isso e não deu certo.. Não me exibiu nada no console..

Comment: if (xhr.status == 200) {

        
      for (var i = 0; i <= curso.length; i++) {
        //Faça o que quiser acessando os objetos do array pelo indice
        //utilizando o i como exemplo abaixo.

        console.log("video: " + curso[i].video);
        console.log("descricao: " + curso[i].descricao);
      }
      
  
    }

Comment: Francis, você chegou a colocar um break point e ver se há alguma coisa na variável **curso**? 
pois com o **if** se não tiver valor nela não irá aparecer mesmo.

Comment: Então, na verdade não estou te entendendo bem. Eu só precisa pegar os dados que eu já pegava antes e fazer um for ou um foreach para exibir outros. eu nem tinha essa variável curso no meu código.. Não estou entendendo sua resposta e se eu soubesse tanta coisa, não estaria aqui no fórum...rs

Comment: Francis, com "variável curso" estava me referindo ao trecho:
 _let curso = xhr.responseText;_
 _curso = JSON.parse(curso);_

De qualquer forma, tente assim: 
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      let curso = xhr.responseText;
      curso = JSON.parse;
      let video = '';
      for(var i=0; i<=curso.length;i++)
      {
       console.log("Vídeo: " + curso[i].video);
        console.log("descricao: " + curso[i].descricao);
        //ou 
         document.querySelector('#curso-descricao').innerHTML += curso[i].descricao;
      }
    }

Comment: Então, testei aqui, mas nem os avisos do console.log aparecerma...

Comment: Opa... vi um erro aqui que eu tinha cometido.. aí consertei e apareceu o seguinte erro: aula-por-curso.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'video' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (aula-por-curso.js:32)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o forEach para isso.

Neste exemplo vamos usar a sua variável `video`:

```
video.forEach(function(curso) {
    var retornoVideo = document.querySelector('#video');
    return retornoVideo.innerHTML += curso.video;
});
```

Veja se isso funciona e me diga se ajudou ou não.

Comment: Olá, fiz desta forma e não apareceu nada não..  que posso fazer?     if (xhr.status == 200) {


      video.forEach(function (curso) {
        var retornoVideo = document.querySelector('#video');
        return retornoVideo.innerHTML += curso.video;
      });

    }

Comment: Publica seu código no jsFiddle para eu analisar, por favor.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/francisVagnerDaLuz/o1hdgg8s/